# What shape provides the best square drill bit?

Tags: geometry, area

The square drill bit is based on the Reuleaux triangle. The Reuleaux triangle can drill about $98.77$% of a square. Specifically, the maximum fraction of a square that it can drill without drilling outside the square is $2\sqrt{3} + \pi/6 - 3.$ Is there any drill bit that can mathematically drill a greater fraction of the square while, at all times, touching all four sides of the square (so that its rotation is restricted)? All such drill bits must be shapes of constant width.

Comment: The fraction of the square is dictated by the 'radius' nothing else.